# How to handle multiple missing keys in a dict?

Tags: python, api, dictionary, keyerror

I'm using an API to get basic information about shops in my area, name of shop, address, postcode, phone number etc… The API returns back a long list about each shop, but I only want some of the data from each shop.

I created a for loop that just takes the information that I want for every shop that the API has returned. This all works fine.

Problem is not all shops have a phone number or a website, so I get a `KeyError` because the key `website` does not exist in every return of a shop. I tried to use `try` and `except` which works but only if I only handle one thing, but a shop might not have a phone number and a website, which leads to a second `KeyError`.

What can I do to check for every key in my `for` loop and if a key is found missing to just add the value `"none"`?

My code:

```
import requests
import geocoder
import pprint

g = geocoder.ip('me')
print(g.latlng)
latitude, longitude = g.latlng
URL = "https://discover.search.hereapi.com/v1/discover"
latitude = xxxx
longitude = xxxx
api_key = 'xxxxx' # Acquire from developer.here.com
query = 'food'
limit = 12

PARAMS = {
            'apikey':api_key,
            'q':query,
            'limit': limit,
            'at':'{},{}'.format(latitude,longitude)
         }

# sending get request and saving the response as response object
r = requests.get(url = URL, params = PARAMS)
data = r.json()
#print(data)


for x in data['items']:
    title = x['title']
    address = x['address']['label']
    street = x['address']['street']
    postalCode = x['address']['postalCode']
    position = x['position']
    access = x['access']
    typeOfBusiness = x['categories'][0]['name']
    contacts = x['contacts'][0]['phone'][0]['value']

   try:
         website = x['contacts'][0]['www'][0]['value']
    except KeyError:
         website = "none"

    resultList = {
    'BUSINESS NAME:':title,
    'ADDRESS:':address,
    'STREET NAME:':street,
    'POSTCODE:':postalCode,
    'POSITION:':position,
    'POSITSION2:':access,
    'TYPE:':typeOfBusiness,
    'PHONE:':contacts,
    'WEBSITE:':website
    }

    print("--"*80)

    pprint.pprint( resultList)
```

Comment: instead of using direct accessing using key, use `get` method on dictionary eg `dict.get("<key>", None)` in this way if key is not found then it will give/assign `None` to that key

Comment: Thats also something I tried but some data from the API is a list of data and `.get` won't work. For example `'contacts': [{'phone': [{'value': '+447415029531'}]}]`

Comment: this is small example for simple key: value pair, for other pair you need to add more filters to get exact data which you want

Comment: I can get the data just fine, I'm looking for how to handle an `KeyError` for all the variables in my for loop because not every shop will have a website or phone number

Comment: As @sahasrara62 wrote, use `dict.get(key, None)` so like this: `website = x.get("contacts",[{}])[0].get("www", [{}])[0].get("value", None)` that way you don't have to handle the error, as no error will be raised

Answer (score 0):

I think a good way to handle it would be to use the [`operator.itemgetter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) to create a callable the will attempt to retrieve all the keys at once, and if any aren't found, it will generate a `KeyError`.

A short demonstration of what I mean:

```
from operator import itemgetter


test_dict = dict(name="The Shop", phone='123-45-6789', zipcode=90210)

keys = itemgetter('name', 'phone', 'zipcode')(test_dict)
print(keys)  # -> ('The Shop', '123-45-6789', 90210)

keys = itemgetter('name', 'address', 'phone', 'zipcode')(test_dict)
# -> KeyError: 'address'
```